# DataStage gives error using partitioned reads to Netezza

Tags: netezza, datastage

Very often we are unable to use Partitioned reads in Netezza connector.

**Example**

When partitioned read = Yes and Generated SQL at Runtime = Yes this works:

```
SELECT "Firma", "KundeNr", "ArtikkelNr"," LagerstedNr" 
FROM dwhusr."TI_FT_Salg"
```

When Generated SQL at Runtime = No and the query is Autogenerated by DataStage (or we write it our selves) the query looks like this:

```
SELECT "Firma", "KundeNr", "ArtikkelNr"," LagerstedNr" 
FROM dwhusr."TI_FT_Salg" 
WHERE mod(datasliceid,[[node-count]])=[[node-number]]
```

It will then throw an error:

> DB_TI_FT_Salg: Unexpected ODBC error occurred. Reason: [SQLCODE=42000][Native=27] ERROR:  'SELECT "Firma", "KundeNr", "ArtikkelNr"," LagerstedNr" FROM dwhusr."TI_FT_Salg" where mod(datasliceid,[[node-count]])=[[node-number]] limit 0'
>   error ^ found "[" (at char 102) expecting an identifier found a keyword (CC_NZMetadataHelper::describeResultSet, file CC_NZMetadataHelper.cpp, line 5 622)

Please help!